# Can I uncrop a numpy array/OpenCV image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

In C++, when I cropped an image, OpenCV simply kept a reference to the original image and added some info about the crop. (If I remember correctly.)
So, there one could "uncrop" the crop and get back the original image.

Is it possible using the Python cv2 interface to "uncrop" the image?

In terms of code, I would like to achieve the following:

```
   cropped = image[y: y+h, x: x+w]
   uncropped = mat_uncrop(cropped)
```

where `uncropped` is to be equal to `image`, pixel-by-pixel.

Comment: As far as I know this is similar to the situation with c++ opencv. You have the original `cv::Mat` and then you can create ROI images from it sharing the same data. The uncropped versoin is the original `cv::Mat`.

Comment: i guess, this question is about, what to do, when you do not have the original image any more

Comment: please add a numpy tag here

Comment: that's a numpy question. I believe numpy retains enough info in its "slices" to "uncrop", or get a reference to the whole data. views/slices retain a reference to the same data. it's kept alive. you might have to dig into its internals. "stride tricks" and whatnot, and guessing. you'll certainly have to guess the original's shape. -- *copies* don't do that, but that's the same in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do that by accessing the [`.base` attribute](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.base.html#numpy.ndarray.base) of a slice.

```py
A = np.eye(10)

B = A[2:8, 2:8]
B[2,2] = 999

assert B.base is A

print(B.flags)

print(B.base)
```

```py
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

[[  1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0. 999.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.]]
```